# Which is more efficient way to save bandwidth

Tags: php, database, bandwidth

I'm trying to make my site faster and saving bandwidth as I can

I have an array which has around 100 values for my images and its links, but it will be used in every post and page (around 500.000 post pages), it's easy for me to make it as a database table or make it as a php array

My question: Which is more efficient way to save bandwidth ?

Create a database table for my value: column 1 for `image name` and column 2 for `image link`

or

Create a php array inside my code

```
$imagesArray = ('ball', 'pin', ...);

$linksArray = array();    
foreach($imagesArray as $image){
    $linksArray[] = '<img src="/imagesFolder'.$image.'.jpg" alt="'.$image.'" />';
}
```

Comment: Neither of these options saves bandwidth in any way - to save bandwidth, reduce the volume of data that you're sending in the response

Comment: Why so many images? Are you displaying all of them on each page?

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm afraid I can't reduce it.

Comment: @relentless Yep, I need to replace some words to its image, for example pin or ball

Comment: Perhaps using a sprite map rather than individual images